# Keras GRU not training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Trying to get some experience with AI on time series data.  So I wrote something with creates a simple sequence and ask the AI to say if in 1440 timesteps it will be higher, lower or within 1.0 of the last number in the sequence.

I am attempting to accomplish this with a GRU or LTSM.  But neither seems to train correctly.  The categorical accuracy sits around 30-40% (seems like it chooses a single answer and sticks on it).  I've tried both GRU and LTSM, different sizes, more dense layers, less dense layers, more items in my sequence, etc etc.

Please excuse if any of this is not particularly pretty Python, coming from C/C++.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import random
import math

class ShortPredSequence(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __GenerateSequences(self):
        self.x = []
        self.y = []
        
        higher = 0
        lower = 0
        similar = 0
        
        for _ in tqdm(range(0,self.num_seq)):
            sequence = []
            up = round(random.uniform(0, .005), 4)
            down = round(random.uniform(0, .005), 4)
            val = round(random.uniform(1, 1000), 4)
            
            for x in range(0, 480*3):
                if x%2 == 0:
                    val += up
                else:
                    val -= down
                
                sequence.append([val])
            self.x.append(sequence)
            
            diff = ((up - down) * 480*3)
            y = None
            if diff > 1.0:
                higher += 1
                y = [[1.0],[0.0],[0.0]]
            elif diff < -1.0:
                lower += 1
                y = [[0.0],[0.0],[1.0]]
            else:
                similar += 1
                y = [[0.0],[1.0],[0.0]]
            self.y.append(y)
                
        print(higher,lower,similar)
    
    def __init__(self, numSeq, batchSize=32):
        self.batch_size = batchSize
        self.num_seq = numSeq
        self.__GenerateSequences()
    
    def __len__(self):
        return int(math.floor(self.num_seq/self.batch_size))
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        lower = index * self.batch_size
        upper = lower + self.batch_size
        return np.array(self.x[lower:upper]), np.array(self.y[lower:upper])

sequence = ShortPredSequence(1000, batchSize=64)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.GRU(32),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="sigmoid"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="sigmoid"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="sigmoid")
])

model.compile(optimizer="adadelta", 
              loss="categorical_crossentropy", 
              metrics="categorical_accuracy")
model.fit(sequence, epochs=5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shape of (X,y) in your code is `(64, 1440, 1)` and `(64, 3, 1)` respectively, that means you have `batch_size=64, timesteps=1440, num_feature=1` in input data and output contains 3 samples of one feature per one batch.

The model has to classify 3 diferent classes which are categorical data. In that case you have to either make the `y_data` as `(64,)` elements where each element represent one class or one-hot encode like `[[0,0,1][0,1,0],[1,0,0]]`.
I think the model in this code is trying to learn multiple outputs for every input sample.(You need use model-subclassing or functional API for multiple-input/multiple output usecases).

I modified your code a like below

```
class ShortPredSequence(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

  def __init__(self, numSeq, batchSize=32):
    self.batch_size = batchSize
    self.num_seq = numSeq
    self.__GenerateSequences()
  def __GenerateSequences(self):
    self.x = []
    self.y = []
    
    higher = 0
    lower = 0
    similar = 0
    
    for i in range(0,self.num_seq):
        sequence = []
        up = round(random.uniform(0, .005), 4)
        down = round(random.uniform(0, .005), 4)
        val = round(random.uniform(1, 1000), 4)
        
        for i in range(0, 480*3):
            if i%2 == 0:
                val += up
            else:
                val -= down
            
            sequence.append([val])
        self.x.append(sequence)
        
        diff = ((up - down) * 480*3)
        y = None
        if diff > 1.0:
            higher += 1
            y = 2
        elif diff < -1.0:
            lower += 1
            y = 0
        else:
            similar += 1
            y = 1
        self.y.append(y)
            
    # print(higher,lower,similar)
    # print(self.x)

  def __len__(self):
    return int(math.floor(self.num_seq/self.batch_size))

  def __getitem__(self, index):
    lower = index * self.batch_size
    upper = lower + self.batch_size
    return np.array(self.x[lower:upper]), np.expand_dims(np.array(self.y[lower:upper]), axis=-1)

model = tf.keras.Sequential(
          [
            tf.keras.layers.GRU(32),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.zeros),
            tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x * 200)
          ]
                         )

 model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), 
          loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=["accuracy"])
 model.fit(sequence, epochs=10)
```

The accuracy fluctuates but the value is changing.

```
Output:

Epoch 1/5
15/15 [==============================] - 6s 183ms/step - loss: 1.8426 - accuracy: 0.4531
Epoch 2/5
15/15 [==============================] - 3s 183ms/step - loss: 1.3448 - accuracy: 0.3760
Epoch 3/5
15/15 [==============================] - 3s 184ms/step - loss: 1.1640 - accuracy: 0.3938
Epoch 4/5
15/15 [==============================] - 3s 183ms/step - loss: 1.1139 - accuracy: 0.4667
Epoch 5/5
15/15 [==============================] - 3s 183ms/step - loss: 1.1297 - accuracy: 0.3802
```

I am not an expert but I just gave a try and that's what I think it is.

Comment: You are correct about that problem.  For the record of others, in the end I've had to also normalize my data to get it to train correctly.  Thanks for giving it a look.

Comment: Glad! it atleast helped to some extent.